# Mocking nested function returning Deferred in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write a Jasmine test for a module that uses a jQuery ajax wrapper library named [jquery.rest](https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest)

This module under test:

```
var module = function() {

  function getData(callback) {

    IP.read().done(function (data) {
        console.log("done");
        callback(data);
    });
  }

  return {
    getData: getData
  }

}();
```

The `client` and `IP` variables are declared in a different file, like so:

```
var client = new $.RestClient('/rest/api/');
var IP = client.add('ip');
```

I would like to mock the `read()` function so that it would return a Json payload that I define in my test.
The `read()` method returns a `$.Deferred` object.

I have tried different approaches (using Jasmine spies) but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

1. spy `$.ajax()` and call fake function that returns your own deferred

   Contra: you indirectly test the library
2. mock `$.RestClient`s interface and return your own deferred

   Contra: more work to mock the library when not only testing the callback is required. (The more complicated your mocking the more error prone your test is.)

---

**TL;DR** Skip this if this is known.

But first let's look at how RestClient works... It has two basic objects, a *Resource* and a *Verb*. The RestClient is actually a `Resource` object (1). `Resource` objects will return another `Resource` object when `add()`ing a rest fragment (2). The pre-defined verb `read` will return a `Verb` instance's `call` method (3).

1. https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/blob/gh-pages/dist/jquery.rest.js#L382
2. https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/blob/gh-pages/dist/jquery.rest.js#L241
3. https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/blob/gh-pages/dist/jquery.rest.js#L245

From the bottom to the top of that chain a `request` method is accessible from the `call()` Method (4). If not explicitly overridden it defaults to `$.ajax()`. (5)

4. https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/blob/gh-pages/dist/jquery.rest.js#L174
5. https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/blob/gh-pages/dist/jquery.rest.js#L66

If not configured differently, a call to `read()` will result in a call to `$.ajax()`, returning a promise.

So, when doing new `new $.RestClient().add("...").add("...").read()` you'll get what you'd get with `$.ajax()`.

---

**Variant 1:**

```
describe("getData()", function(){
        // Handle to ajax()' deferred, scoped to the
        // describe so the fake ajax() and the it()
        // have access to it
    var def,
        underTest;

    beforeEach(function(){
        // Mock $.ajax (or what a Verb calls in the end)
        // assign "def" with a deferred and return it,
        // the test can then resolve() or reject() it
        spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function(opts) {
            def = $.Deferred();
            return def;
        });

        // This is under test
        underTest = new UnderTest();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        // Ensure a missing call of ajax() will fail the test
        def = null;
    });

    it("should call callback on successful read", function() {
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");
        // Indirectly call ajax() which will create def
        underTest.getData(callback);
        // Resolve the deferred to succeed the response
        def.resolve({a: 1});
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith({a: 1});
    });

    it("should not call callback on failed read", function(){
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");
        underTest.getData(callback);
        def.reject();
        expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The fake is returning a deferred, not a promise, but in this case it's OK since it has the same interface, and nothing/no one should reject or resolve the deferred here except us.

**Variant 2:**

```
describe("getData()", function(){
        // Store original reference
    var origRestClient,
        // See first code block
        def,
        underTest;

    // Mock thr Resouce object
    function MockResource() { }

    // Simplify the behaviour of this mock,
    // return another Mock resource
    MockResource.prototype.add = function() {
        return new MockResource();
    };

    // What Verb.call() would do, but directly
    // return a deferred
    MockResource.prototype.read = function() {
        def = $.Deferred();
        return def;
    };

    beforeEach(function(){
        // Replace RestClient
        origRestClient = $.RestClient;
        $.RestClient = MockResource;

        underTest = new UnderTest();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        // Restore RestClient
        $.RestClient = origRestClient;
        def = null;
    });

    it("should call callback on successful read", function() {
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");
        underTest.getData(callback);
        def.resolve({a: 1});
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith({a: 1});
    });

    it("should not call callback on failed read", function(){
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy("callback");
        underTest.getData(callback);
        def.reject();
        expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The mocking of `Resouce` needs more work than what I've done if you'd like to test the path and request data too, with the above code this is not possible.

Comment: Bad ass answer! Thanks